# C++ (VS2012) stdio: Can't read one-byte file if that byte is 09h

Tags: c++, stdio

The code is very simple.

```
unsigned char a_byte;
ifstream a_file("C:/file.bin", ios_base::binary);
if (a_file.is_open() && a_file.good())
{
    a_file.seekg(0);
    a_file >> a_byte;
    a_file.close();
}
```

The problem is that it won't read 09h from a one-byte file - I just get zero in the a_byte var. It does work with different values. What's the reason?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stream classes' `operator>>` will skip whitespace before reading into the target variable. Here the char value `09h` is TAB, which is counted as whitespace and skipped.

If you want to read every single character, try the `get` function.